# Get Unique ID using the other column using mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, yii2, uid

I have two tables.

- Action
- Company

Action is related to company by `company_id`

So in the action table, `action_id` is the primary key and auto incremented. Based on the `company_id` the information will be displayed. If the user has `company_id` 1 assigned to him and he is logged in he can do actions associated with `company_id` 1. A different company will have different actions with lots of `action_id`s. For every company I want to create a unique `action_id`. How can I achieve this?

For example:
 There are 3 companies using my actions module

**A company**, **B company**, **C company**

1. **A company** creates 10 actions first.

   - Now we have `action_id`s from 1-10 assigned in actions table.
2. Now **B company** creates 5 actions.

   - Now we have `action_id` s from 11-15 assigned in actions table
3. Now **C company** creates 5 actions.

   - Now we have `action_id`s from 16-20 assigned.
   - So when I display `action_id`s in **A company** it will displayed from 1- 10
   - But in **B and C company** they will have wrongs id's displayed.
   - As far as the companies knowledge that is the first action they have created but action_id will be displayed as 11, 12 and so on.
   - How do I solve this issue?

Expected result:

[image]

Comment: This seems like a really flawed design without a more thorough explanation. What are you attempting to achieve by doing this?

Comment: Updated question with example provided now

Comment: Yes but for instance, what are actions? Why do you need to generate a unique number based off a company id and action id? What is this attempting to solve?

Comment: its a module I'm working on. In a company they can create actions to perform some task...just like project managament tool for instance

Comment: So you're attempting to get a continuous id for each individual company then? What for, naming?

Comment: Yes..that is what I am trying to do

Comment: You can simply count (iterate) your results. It is not a good approach to save the `#` in the database. When you delete action `5`, you have to reorder action `6-10` which is bad. Simply display in your output the first result with #1, the second result with #2 and so on.

Comment: I don't want to re-order..I want to keep the count of actions(including deleted)

Answer (score 0):

You can use concat(company_id , "_", action_id) as unique_id

-> [mysql-concat-function](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-concat-function.htm)

Comment: Nope I want to display them to the users so that they have track of their actions....

Answer (score 0):

I would use `INSERT...SELECT` when inserting the new ids to the table, so that you can be assured you have the proper count:

```
INSERT INTO action (company_id, uid)
SELECT :company AS company_id, COUNT(*) + 1 AS uid
FROM action
WHERE action.company_id = :company
```

Of course, this means that upon deletion your ids will no longer be continuous. If you want to automatically generate unique ids then it becomes a little more tricky with pure sql. I would honestly just use something like an array index (if the number is the important part) for the naming at this point, instead of storing it manually, especially since it is calculated data.

```
$actions = /* your actions retrieval, assume associative array */;
$actions[0]; //uid == 1, index == 0, etc
```

Comment: Yes that is the issue...I have php function where it counts and add's puts in the uid but on deletion it is not continuous...that is why I posted the question.

Comment: if(count($company) > 0){
                $model->action_uid = count($company)+1;
            }else{
                $model->action_uid = 1;
            }

Comment: Right, at that point I think it would make sense to not use mysql for that. When you retrieve the actions, you already have an entire array of all of the available actions for the company. If the purpose of the `uid` is for naming the actions, you can do that by something like the array index. If you need to delete it later, you already have the (completely unique) `action_id`. I still do not see any purpose for `uid` beyond that. The user does not have to see the `action_id` or `uid`, you can show them whatever you like.

Comment: its just to keep track of number of actions they have created(includes deleted actions)

Comment: You could just mark the action in the database as "deleted" then, and not actually remove it. Or increment an "action" counter if it's purely for a raw number. You need to further expand upon your question (specifically about how these `uid`s are shown to the user and the specific purposes of them) if you're still looking for a more detailed answer.